# Uno App exception launch missing windows.color

Tags: uno-platform

I just migrated my app to use Uno 4.0 and am having a few issues.  When I go to build and run the project- I am getting this error:

> System.MissingFieldException
> Message=Field not found: Windows.UI.Color Windows.UI.Colors.Black Due to: Could not find field in class

I do use the colors in my MaterialColorPaletteOverride.xaml.  I currently have Uno.Material at 1.0.507.  I plan to migrate that- but would like to resolve this issue first.  This code did work before the migration- so I think somehow the colors are referenced differently now.

I am using the following packages:

- Uno.Core 4.0.1
- Uno.Material 1.0.0.-dev.507
- Uno.UI 4.0.7
- Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.7.0

Here is my snippet from my MaterialColorPaletteOverride.xaml:

```xml
    <ResourceDictionary
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:local="using:NeatApp.Shared">
           <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
           <!-- Light Theme -->
           <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
               <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialOnBackgroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
           </ResourceDictionary>
           <!-- Dark Theme -->
           <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
               <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialOnBackgroundBrush" Color="White"/>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>    
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually that you are using an incompatible version of `Uno.Material`. `1.0.0.-dev.507` is compatible with Uno.UI 3.x, but not with 4.x, due to the fact that there were many breaking changes (including changes in `Windows.UI.Colors`). You will also need to upgrade `Uno.Material` to a 4.x compatible version to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  I will migrate to the newer Uno Material.